# I need to replace literal \n with newline in shell

Tags: shell, replace, newline

We receive a file which is essentially an ssh token key.
This upon inception has values, say

```
Foo\nBarFoo,\nFoo\nBarFoo
```

Now, I want to replace these with

```
Foo
BarFoo,
Foo
BarFoo
```

I have tried `sed` and `tr` commands by copying the entire key in a variable.
One thing that seemed to work was `: %s/\\n/\r/g`, but this is not acceptable since I cannot open the `vi` editor.

I recently tried `echo -e 'Foo\nBarFoo,\nFoo\nBarFoo`, but want to be it more subtle.

Comment: What is the problem using that pattern with sed?

Comment: [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) answers your question. Search before you ask.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't it work? `I have tried sed and tr commands by copying the entire key in a variable` what have you tried exactly? Just give example command, example output, such small code snippets help a lot. Note that there is `ed` command, which exactly executes `vi`-like commands in batch mode. And, wouldn't just `echo ': %s/\\n/\r/g' | vi input_file` work?

Comment: @Mihir that post is about substituting a newline with another character. This is about substituting the string `\n` with a newline. These are not duplicates.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks for pointing that out, my mistake.

Comment: Why not just `echo -e $(<file)`?

Comment: Thanks David. But this is exactly what I am using now (echo -e 'pointed in the main body above')

Answer (score 3):

You are facing the problem because you are using `OSX` or `BSD` probably. With `GNU sed`, `'s/\\n/\n/g’` should have worked.

For `POSIX sed`, use this,

```
echo "Foo\nBarFoo,\nFoo\nBarFoo" | sed 's/\\n/\
/g'
```

Comment: I also tried `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`, to replace the the literal with newline.